# What does it mean to integrate a Brownian motion with respect to time?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I am reading about stochastic process, but could not make sense if one equation I encountered. Can anyone help me understand it?

The equation states that suppose R(s) is an interest rate process, then the discount process is $D(t)=e^{- \int_0^t R(s)ds} $.

Suppose R(t)=W(t) is a simple Brownian motion, what does $\int_0^t R(s)ds$ mean?
Is it a Lebesgue integral? Or is it an Ito's integral? How to interpret it intuitively?

This is from chapter 5 of Shreve's stochastic calculus for finance, equation 5.2.17 on page 215.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Brownian Motion has continuous paths with probability 1 thus$\int_{0}^{t} W_s ds$ is well define. Now set $f(x)=x^3$. By application of Ito's lemma, we have
$$f(W_t)=f(W_0)+\int_{0}^{t}f'(W_s)dW_s+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t}f''(W_s)ds$$
$$W^3(t)=3\int_{0}^{t}W^2_s\,dW_s+3\int_{0}^{t}W_sds$$
therefore
$$\int_{0}^{t}W_sds=\frac{1}{3}W^3(t)-\int_{0}^{t}W^2_s\,dW_s$$

**Note**

The Itô integral can be defined in a manner similar to the Riemann–Stieltjes integral, that is as a limit in probability of Riemann sums; such a limit does not necessarily exist pathwise. Suppose that $W_t$ is a Wiener process and that $X_t$ is a right-continuous (cadlag), adapted and locally bounded process if $I=\{t_0,t_1,\cdots,t_n\}$ is a sequence of partitions of $[0,t]$  with mesh going to zero, then the Itô integral of $X_t$ with respect to $W_t$ up to time t is a random variable
$$\int_{0}^{t}X_sdW_s=\underset{n\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{X({{t}_{i-1}})(W({{t}_{i}})-W({{t}_{i-1}})})$$
Set $X_s=W^2_s$, we  have
$$\int_{0}^{t}W^2_sdW_s=\underset{n\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{W^2({{t}_{i-1}})(W({{t}_{i}})-W({{t}_{i-1}})})$$
**Edit**
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{0}^t W_s \,ds & = & \int_0^t \int_0^t \mathbf{1}_{[0,s]} (u) \,dW_u \,ds \\
& = & \int_0^t \int_0^t \mathbf{1}_{[0,s]} (u) \,ds  \,dW_u\\
& = &  \int_0^t (t-u) \,dW_u\\
\end{eqnarray}
Indeed
$$\int_{0}^{t}{{{W}_{s}}}ds\sim N\left( 0\,,\,\frac{1}{3}{{t}^{3}} \right)$$

Comment: What is the interpretation of the integral?

Comment: Ito integral ...?

Comment: My impression is that itos integral is integrating with respect to W instead of time. This integral is with respect to time. Unless I am not getting it right, I don't think this is itos integral

Comment: $\int_{0}^{t}W_s ds$ is a stochastic process

Comment: Well I agree that W is continuous, but that does not prove that the integral is well defined. In fact, what I am asking is the definition of it

Comment: What means $\int ...ds\, ?$

Comment: That is the question  I am  asking in the post...

Comment: $\int_{0}^{t} W_s ds$ is not Ito's integral.

Comment: Okay...what is it?

Comment: $\int_{0}^{t}W_sds=\frac{1}{3}W^3(t)-\int_{0}^{t}W^2_s\,dW_s$

Comment: Oh come on, that cannot be the definition of it

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It totally makes sense now.

Comment: What is your field of study?

Comment: I study math, but am new to stochastic processes

Comment: I was reading through your edit one more time. What is $1_[0,s] (u)$ again?

Comment: if $x\in[0,s]$  then $\mathbb{1}_{[0,s]}(x)=1$ and  o.w $ \mathbb{1}_{[0,s]}(x)=0$

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki I have two questions: 1) it is not clear to me in this step $\int_{0}^{t}W_sds=\frac{1}{3}W^3(t)-\int_{0}^{t}W^2_s\,dW_s \sim N\left( 0\,,\,\frac{1}{3}{{t}^{3}} \right)$  why $-\int_{0}^{t}W^2_s\,dW_s$ has no impact at all on the found distribution.
2)why $\int_0^t \mathbf{1}_{[0,s]} (u)ds = (t-u)$ shouldn't be $min(t,s)-0$ ?

Comment: Does the integral have a closed form for certain $W_s$?

Answer (score 11):

It might be easier to think about if we abstract a little.  Brownian motion is just a continuous, time dependent random variable determined by some probability space $(X,\mathcal F, P)$.  Let us view it as a function of two variables, $f(x,t)$.  If $x$ is fixed, we have a continuous function, $f_x(t)=f(x,t)$, and we can compute it's integral $F(x,t)=F_x(t)=\int_0^t f_x(s) ds$, where we have just taken the usual integral of a continuous function (Riemann, Lebesgue, whatever, all the definitions agree for nice continuous functions).  Thus, we have a transformation of the space of time dependent continuous random variables on $X$ (i.e., functions on $X\times \mathbb R$).  The fact that we are working in particular with brownian motion doesn't enter into things.

A more complicated question is what it means to integrate a function or a random variable *with respect to Brownian motion*.  This gets you to the Ito integral (and other similar variants) which are more subtle.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So when you write a Brownian motion in terms of f(x, t), what does x represent? Is it an element of the sample space X?

Comment: @user1559897 Yes, it is the sample space that (in this case) the Brownian  motion is based on.  In practice, this sample space isn't actually accessible, and instead people talk about Brownian motion being defined by properties, but by writing it in these terms you have a nice and simple theoretical perspective of what kind of things you're dealing with.  I should note that nowhere above did we actually use the fact that the sample space is a probability space.  We did not use $P$ or $\mathcal F$ at all.

Comment: @Aaron can you offer any answer to the more complicated question? I'm having trouble conceptualizing what it *means*

Comment: @Diego In the specific situation of the question, it may be worth considering a discrete time process, where at each time step, inflation devalues your money by a factor of $e^{-x_i}$, and so the cumulative devaluation is $\prod e^{-x_i}=e^{-\sum x_i}$..  But the $x_i$ happen randomly, and you don't know in advance what they will be, and they depend on the possible states of the world (the possibilities of which form a probability space).  The integral is essentially a limit as the time step approaches zero.

Comment: @Aaron could you better explain this sentence: Thus, we have a transformation of the space of time dependent continuous random variables on X (i.e., functions on ×ℝ)? thank you

Comment: @Alias__ The explanation of that sentence is all the sentences that came before it. We have a collection of functions, if we fix one variable they are continuous in the other variable, and we transform them by integrating from 0 to t. I wasn’t saying something new, I was summarizing. That is why the sentence started with “thus”.

Answer (score 5):

There are two types of integrals involving Brownian motion, time integral and itos integral. Here the integral is a time integral, which is just an ordinary Lebesgue integral. The integral itself is also a random variable as it depends on the path of brownian motion.

The interpretation and properties of a time integral should follow those of Lebesgue integrals.

Comment: "There are two types of integrals involving Brownian motion, time integral and itos integral." Don't forget Stratonovich. :) (essentially Ito)